# How to access the relevant documentation for plotLinesAndBands in Highcharts？

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am a newcomer learning Highcharts, and I've been exploring issues related to plotLines. I've noticed that many people mention plotLinesAndBands, but I haven't found any documentation about it on the official website or elsewhere. How can I obtain information about it?

Many mention plotLinesAndBands
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=plotLinesAndBands+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plotLinesAndBands` object serves as the container for storing plotlines or plotBands within the chart configuration.

The documentation outlines how to configure the chart, where plotLines/plotBands are directly specified within the axis, as follows:

```
  yAxis: {
    plotLines: [{
      color: 'blue',
      width: 5,
      value: 5.5
    }],
    plotBands: [{
      color: 'red',
      from: 2,
      to: 4
    }]
  },
```

However, the plotlines or plotBands reside within the plotLinesAndBands object, and you can easily verify this using the devtool:

[image]

If  you find the information unclear and should be mentioned in the documentation, feel free to report it on our github page:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thank you for your response. it has been helpful to me.